# Gain of an active filter without calculating the transfer function with two OP-AMP's

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I need to calculate the gain of the filter without explicitly calculating the transfer function, ie I have to replace the capacitors with an open circuit. The problem is that I've been trying to solve the problem but I do not know how to start. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There's no current through \$R_3\$, so \$V_1=V_o\$; hence the output of the lower op-amp is at or near the negative supply voltage, say \$ -V_s\$.

The upper op-amp is a buffer, therefore \$V_o=V_2=V_1\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}-V_s\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the gain will be zero.

There is a feedback path from the output of the lower opamp to the input of the upper and back through R3 and R4 to the lower opamp.  The feedback is negative as the lower opamp negative input receives the direct output of the upper opamp while the signal is attenuated by R4 and R5 to the non-inverting input.  This statement would not be true if R5 did not exist. This feedback will ensure that the system is DC stable but does not define the gain if Vi is not zero.

Since C2 does not exist the voltage across R3 must be zero (no current into the input of either opamp).

Because there is feedback the opamps will change their output in such a fashion to make the input voltage difference of the opamps zero.

If the voltage across R3 is zero and the voltage across the opamp inputs is zero, so must the voltage across R4.

If the voltage across R4 is zero, the current is zero so the voltage across R5 is also zero as the only current through R5 is that from R4.

If the voltage across R4 and R5 are both zero the output voltage V0 must also be zero independent of the input V1.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize. I already drew the circuit without the capacitors. But I did not realize why the gain is zero. I'm a newcomer to this. Could you explain more in detail the directions of the currents you are referring to please?

Comment: What do you not understand - I thought I explained the steps I went through?

Comment: Why must the voltage across R4 be zero?

Comment: Because the voltage across R3 is zero and the voltage across the opamp inputs is zero so must that across R4.

Comment: If the overall gain is zero, Vo is zero, and if Vo is zero, V- of the upper op-amp is zero. Also, if Vo is zero, the output of the lower op-amp is zero, so V+ of the upper op-amp is not zero. If V+ is not zero, and V- is zero, then Vo cannot be zero. Hence there's a conflict. Therefore the initial proposition that the overall gain is zero cannot be true.

Comment: @Chu "the output of the lower op-amp is zero".  That is not a correct statement. The ideal op-amp has infinite gain and its output can be anything even when its input is zero.

Comment: Multisim shows that the output depends on the ratio of R1:R2. For example, if all resistors are 10k except R1 which is 2k, and the input is a 5 V ramp, the output is also a ramp but is zero for input values <2 V

Comment: That would be because the lower opamp has saturated.  That opamp has to cancel out the Vin by a current through R2.  When the opamp output cannot go anymore negative Vin will get through to the upper opamp and you will see that effect. Try plotting the lower opamp output.

Comment: Yes that's exactly correct, the output tracks the input with an offset when the lower amp is saturated, and is zero when not saturated.

Comment: @Chu Then the total gain is zero right? I did not realize how we know the voltage at R3 is zero.

Comment: @KevinWhite Then the total gain is zero right? I did not realize how we know the voltage at R3 is zero.

Comment: The voltage ACROSS R3 is zero because the bias current for the opamps are assumed to be zero (ideal opamps).